# How to Integrate web api code in c# to sensenet?

Tags: c#

I have a problem integrating Web APIs in C# to Sensenet. But I haven't found any solution for that. When I tried using the URL of the API in localhost, the following error occurs:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Where do I place the web API to get the correct output?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Project/newProjectList")]
public string NewProjectList()
{
    string str;
    ModelProjectClass d = new ModelProjectClass();
    str = d.NewProject();
    return str;
}
```

Comment: please show the full controller

Answer (score 0):

If there was `Route` attribute on the top of the `controller` you must change the `Route` attribute on action to this route

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("newProjectList")]
public string NewProjectList()
{
    string str;
    ModelProjectClass d = new ModelProjectClass();
    str = d.NewProject();
    return str;
}
```